# why using Android SurfaceView gives black screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview

I am using SurfaceView to hold Camera object, and I wrapped the view in a FrameLayout.
I also have added an input text box in the same activity where I am holding the camera view. When I click on it, the soft keyboard opens and covers half of the device screen (Galaxy S2), and in this case I was able to see a non-black screen. I am wondering why, when the soft keyboard was opened, the camera starts working, and when I close the soft keyboard it goes back to being black

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity {

private Camera myCamera;
private MyCameraSurfaceView myCameraSurfaceView;
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
private EditText editTextServerIP;

Button myButton;
Button btnUpload;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
boolean recording;
Button btnConnectVideo;
EditText savePath;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //policy to prevent exception when stop record
    //android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    recording = false;

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    // Get Camera for preview
    myCamera = getCameraInstance();
    if (myCamera == null) {
        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Fail to get Camera",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    myCameraSurfaceView = new MyCameraSurfaceView(this, myCamera);
    FrameLayout myCameraPreview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    myCameraPreview.addView(myCameraSurfaceView);

    myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
    myButton.setOnClickListener(myButtonOnClickListener);

    btnUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
    btnUpload.setOnClickListener(btnUploadOnClickListener);

    editTextServerIP = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextServerIP);

    btnConnectVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConnectVideo);
    btnConnectVideo.setOnClickListener(askServerToConvertAndConnectAllVideos);

    savePath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPath); 
}
```

public class MyCameraSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements
            SurfaceHolder.Callback {

```
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public MyCameraSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
            int weight, int height) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events
        // here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // make any resize, rotate or reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was found in the Android 4.0.4 kernel (custom ROM), problem and fix could be found below:
[XDA - android ROM 4.0.4 camera fix](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1772931)

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing in your SurfaceHolder.Callback?  When the soft keyboard opens, it should resize the SurfaceView, which would trigger the surfaceChanged callback.  If you look at the sample code [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera), you need to stop preview when the Surface configuration changes and restart it using the new SurfaceHolder because it might not be the same dimensions as the one you started with.